# OpenMP parallel 'for' doesn't work properly

Tags: c, openmp

The following snippet is from one of the functions of my code:

```
static int i;

#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(i) schedule(static,1)
for (i=0; i<ttm_ic_last; i++)
{
    static int ni, ni1, ni2;
    static double ni_ratio;
    static double temp_e, temp_l;
    ...
}
```

It's odd that when I comment the line starting with `#pragma` it works properly, otherwise the loop doesn't touch at least some of the intended values of `i`. (I'm not sure if 'touch' is the correct  verb here.)

I'm using a workstation with

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
```

I wonder what the cause of this error can be.

Comment: Question; why are you using statics? (ni, ni1 etc.) I would guess that if you use non statics it works as expected.

Comment: Could it be related to the static variables in the loop? Can it be the fact that the index is static?

Comment: Show [mcve], your expected behavior and the actual one.

Comment: @Stefan, each run of this code takes several days and this snippet is from a function which is a bottleneck. So I thought maybe static variables would be faster. Recently I moved those static variables from outside of the loop to inside, and then this situation occurred.

Comment: The thing is; with statics, they have a shared memory space. So they will likely to interfere with each other across the threads. Your parallel loops are all looking inside the same box.

Comment: @Stefan, Yes. Now I understand. Previously, they were declared outside the loop and were listed in the `private` clause. I guess OpenMP treated them as auto variables. But when I brought them inside the loop things changed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have an answer, add an answer below. Don't edit the title and put "Solved" in it. Accepted answers perform that function.

Comment: @tadman, I know. But Stefan's comment solved the problem.

Comment: With static definition outside the loop, the private clause asks for each thread to have its own variable with scope inside the parallel region.  Nothing is copied between the one in the outer scope and the inner ones unless you set a firstprivate or lastprivate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer by Stefan)

Don't use `static` variables when OpenMP threads are involved.

The thing is; with statics, they have a shared memory space. So they will likely to interfere with each other across the threads. Your parallel loops are all looking inside the same box.